# Pygame failing to load mp3 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, mp3, pygame-mixer

I am trying to load a mp3 file in pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.13) but i am getting an error here is the code i am using:

```
self.jump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:/Users/IAMAUSER/OneDrive/Desktop/Pro/Pygame/audio/jump.mp3')
```

I am using "self." because i am doing this in a class and yes i have imported pygame

Error i am getting:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\IAMAUSER\OneDrive\Desktop\Pro\Pygame\import pygame.py", line 139, in <module> player.add(Player()) File "c:\Users\IAMAUSER\OneDrive\Desktop\Pro\Pygame\import pygame.py", line 18, in __init__ self.jump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:/Users/IAMAUSER/OneDrive/Desktop/Pro/Pygame/audio/jump.mp3') pygame.error: Unable to open file 'C:/Users/IAMAUSER/OneDrive/Desktop/Pro/Pygame/audio/jump.mp3'`

The `player.add(Player())` is not the problem i think

I expected for it to load the sound so i could use
`self.jump_sound.play()`
to play the sound

Comment: For some reason pygame just does not accept .mp3 format i tried with a .wav format and it worked
Either this or the file was to short or corrupted

Comment: Of course pygame supports mp3. Read the documentation: [`pygame.mixer.music`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html). This is a problem with your system.